# Why are the contents of my Outline and Bookmarks disappearing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, salesforce

The contents of my Outline view keep disappearing (nothing in the window) in eclipse (Indigo).

I've been trying to use Bookmarks as a workaround, but regularly after a I save, my booksmarks all get cleared!

I'm using the Force.com IDE plugin - I think it might be a bug in there.

Anyone know if there's a way to fix this? It's hard to navigate without an outline or bookmarks.

thanks

Comment: I don't believe that Indigo is supported.

From the [Force.com IDE FAQ](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_IDE_FAQ#What_Eclipse_versions_are_compatible_with_the_Force.com_IDE.3F):

    **What Eclipse versions are compatible with the Force.com IDE?**

    The Force.com IDE plugin works with Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) and 3.5 (Galileo).

Comment: The Outline view should always reflect what's in the active Editor.  How can contents be disappearing?

Comment: It installs and works fine in 3.7, but I tried 3.6 and had the same problems. It's generally not disappearing, it's generally just empty - not there at all. I said disappearing because occasionally it shows up again, but generally it's empty. But it seems like it's just one class I'm having this problem with, it's working with other classes I've tried. I think the problem is I have a @RemoteAction (part of API v22, Spring '11) in this class and the Force.com IDE doesn't support this yet (it's API 20, Winter'11 I think), and that's causing the Outline to break. Maybe there's a log I can check?

Comment: I understand your frustration. I've had problems with the outline when using annotations like (at)future and (at)RemoteAction in Apex classes. That may have something to do with it. They will probably have an update to take care of some of these issues at some point..

Comment: Don't suppose you ever found out why your bookmarks were disappearing?

Comment: No, never did, but I suspect it's related to the Outline problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem now. Anyone else? I don't work with Visualforce much. I don't have Outline for pure classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this with some Salesforce people, it is because I'm using javascript remoting with the @RemoteAction keyword, which is part of API version 22 Spring '11, and nd the Force.com IDE doesn't support this yet. It's currently at API version 20 (Winter'11 I think?). That's causing the Outline to break. Hopefully they'll release an update soon.